# Automatic rotation of rectangles with OpenCV and python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a code for processing images, I am working on analyzing geometric figures, specifically work with rectangles, and I have a function for detecting the rectangles, my problem is this:

I can detect all rectangles but I need to correct the inclination of the detected rectangles, I mean, there are inclunados rectangles diagonally, I need to correct the tilt and move the rectangle to a rectangle straight (90 °)

In the following website: http://www.salvasavall.com/2012/04/rotacion-automatica-de-rectangulos-con.html and author "Salva Savall," I found a c ++ code that fixes the problem but not I understand the code and do not translate to Python.

How Python achievement skew correction of the detected rectangles and pass all rectangles at right rectangles (90 °)?

Comment: Have you tried using `centre, dimensions, theta = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)` ?

Comment: I'm using cv2.minAreaRect (contour), I thought the center returned, size and angle, in that order, but always the third value is a value between 0 and -90. Using the library "Scipy" I can rotate an image using a single line of code, but the only thing I need is to correct the tilt angle and get a straight rectangle.

This code is in rotation: dst = ndimage.rotate (temp, angle)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a brute force approach as I don't know an elegant one :
take three points on the rectangle clockwise with P1 being the higher point

```
P1=(X1,Y1),P2=(X2,Y2),P3=(X3,Y3)
#length of the sides will be 
L1=np.sqrt((X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2)
L2=np.sqrt((X2-X3)^2+(Y2-Y3)^2)
```

now it all depends on around which point you want to rotate it and in what direction if you want to do it around P1 clockwise the new rectangle will be

```
Q1=(X1,Y1)
Q2=(X1+L1,Y1)
Q3=(X1+L1,Y1+L2)
```

clockwise once again I hope this helps